# Is there a way to return current class type in a final method?

Tags: java, class, generics, types, reflection

I have the following situation in java; There is a class that implements a method that is meant to be final but I need the returning type of such method to be exactly that of the class that it calling it. Since I want the method to be final I can't modify the return data type in the subclasses since that would be illegal.

Is there a way to archive this without sacrificing finality and having to override such method for all subclasses that implement it?. Even if the method was not final it would still be faster to implement it this way.

The code would be something like this:

```java
class Parent
{
    public currentClass finalMethod() {...}
}

class Children extends Parent {}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Children c = new Children();
    System.out.print(c.finalMethod().getClass().getName()); // Would print Children
}
```

Tried to use reflection and generics to no avail. Examples:

```java
class Parent
{
    public this.getClass() finalMethod() {...} //Many Errors
    public <extends Parent> finalMethod() {...} // Returns Parent even if called by Child
    public Class<? extends Parent>[] getVecinos() // Returns Class<? extends Parent> thus can't use polymorphism which is the use case
}
```

I know I could use casting but still not the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is that you'll get what you're looking for, as long as `finalMethod` does not generate new instances using other types.

To use your code:

```
class Parent {
    public final Parent finalMethod() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

With that, `c.finalMethod().getClass().getName()` returns `Children`. That's because `this` inside `finalMethod()` is the same object that was created using `new Children()` and `getClass()` returns the runtime class of the object.

That uses inheritance and as long as you can work with `Parent` as the return type, you should be fine. If, however, your objective is to call methods specific to `Children` on the return value of `finalMethod()`, you may need to make `Parent` generic. Something like this:

```
class Parent<C extends Parent<C>> {
    public final Parent<C> finalMethod() {
        //whatever
        return this;
    }
}
class Children extends Parent<Children> {
}
```

And that would make the following code valid, still producing the same output:

```
Parent<Children> c = new Children(); //or Children c = new Children();
System.out.print(c.finalMethod().getClass().getName());
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to make static reference to `Child`-specific methods without prior casting. But it's not the right solution unless it's okay to make `Parent` generic. It's also not fail-safe.

Comment: When trying the second option I still get Children cannot be converted to Parent<Children>

Comment: @BaltasardelSoldeHaro did you change the declaration of `Children` to `extends Parent<Children>`?

Comment: Yes, I changed it.

Comment: I'm not getting that error, @BaltasardelSoldeHaro. Can you please paste both of your class declarations and the main method's body in a new comment?

Comment: Wait, I misspelled the generic. Now it works correctly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No mate, I'm still getting the error. Let's see if you can help me please. My project is in [Github](https://github.com/Balrrach/tsi/tree/master/practica/practica1/GVGAI). You can compile using `ant compile`. In package: `src/tracks/singlePlayer/evaluacion/src_DELSOL_DEHARO_BALTASAR` classes Nodo and NodoEstado implement the talked structure but class AgenteBFS produces error because it doesn't associate NodoEstado with Nodo<NodoEstado>. What could be the reason/problem?

Comment: Just add the declaration of your classes and main method, please. @BaltasardelSoldeHaro

Comment: Is it this line that's failing compilation: `for (NodoEstado nodoVecino : nodoActual.getVecinos())`?

Comment: Yes, that's the problematic line.

Comment: Okay. This answer doesn't speak to that use case. If you want to use it like that, then this code would have to make `finalMethod` be declared as `public final C finalMethod()` (assuming Parent can return a C object). In your case, that would be `public ArrayList<C> getVecinos()` in `Nodo` for that line of code to compile.

Comment: It's true that fixes the problem but if I do that I would have to change line `ArrayList<Nodo<C>> vecinos = new ArrayList<Nodo<C>>();` to `ArrayList<C> vecinos = new ArrayList<C>();`. And then I get errors like `The method add(C) in the type ArrayList<C> is not applicable for the arguments (Nodo)` when trying to fill the vector with current class elements.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. That's why I noted in the answer that your `finalMethod` must be creating instances of the concrete type. But given that you're using the constructor from `this.getClass()`, you must be getting the correct constructor of `C`. It must be about casting. I may be mistaken, but I guess you should be able to cast: `(C)ctor.newInstance(...)`. That will give an unchecked cast warning, but I think it will be safe.

Comment: You are absolutely right and I thank you a lot for your help. God bless you. Just one last problem I'm having. When I try to get any constructor using `getConstructor()` I get `NoSuchElementException` which means no constructor with the given parameters was found. Do you know perhaps what could be the problem. I've tried: `var ctor = this.getClass().getConstructor(new Class[] { Vector2d.class, NodoEstado.class, Types.ACTIONS.class });` and `var ctor = this.getClass().getConstructor();` with no success but both constructors are defined in NodoEstado. @ernest_k

Comment: @BaltasardelSoldeHaro I see the constructor is declared as `NodoEstado(Vector2d _coordinates, Nodo<NodoEstado> _parent, Types.ACTIONS _parentAction)`. So your code must be `var ctor = this.getClass().getConstructor(new Class[] { Vector2d.class, Nodo.class, Types.ACTIONS.class });` (parameter types must match, you can't substitute `Nodo` for its subclass `NodoEstado` when looking up the constructor. You can still pass an object of the subclass type when invoking it.

Comment: I tried it too but it doesn't work neither, I get the same error: `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: @BaltasardelSoldeHaro Let's be clear first... What exception are you getting? `NoSuchElementException`, or `NoSuchMethodException`? The next thing you can try is to call `getDeclaredConstructor` instead of `getConstructor`

Comment: I'm getting `NoSuchElementException` in file Nodo in method `getVecinos()`. I've pushed the changes made. You can run the code if you need to with `ant run`.

Comment: Ok, I don't really know where the error is but I think is in another place. I'm going to study the code deeply. Don't waste your time here you have more than answered my question. Again, thanks a lot friend.

Comment: Yes, the error was in a different part. Again, thanks a lot for your help.